# How to make button change value on click in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button

I'm having a lot of problems getting this to work, I don't quite understand how the view sends info to controller, so it can be manipulated.

I have a button, which when clicked should change its value. Values changes between Yes / No.
When the button is clicked it needs to change the corresponding value in the database, then in the view I already have the logic that decides button value.

Here's some code, how I imagine it working...
`show.html.erb` view

```
<% status = @problem.status? 'No' : 'Yes' %>
<%= link_to status, @problem, :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
```

In my ProblemsController

```
def show
  @problem = Problem.find(params[:id])

  @problem.status ? @problem.status : (@problem.status == 'false')
end

def solve
end
```

I'm not sure if I should change the database value in show method or create another one. The problem is that I don't know how to communicate from the view to the controller. How can I do this?

I was considering adding `:data { solve: @problem.status }` to `link_to` tag, not sure if that would help though. So far I'm unable to enter solve method (I tried adding `:action => 'solve'` or `:action => '/problems/solve`' ), which didn't help. The following is something I just tried, but it doesn't work (doesn't go to solve action in ProblemsController).

```
<%= link_to status, @problem, :controller => 'problems', :action => 'solve', :class => 'btn' %>
```

I would definitely appreciate some help! Any ideas?

**Edit**: Added code for params in controller, which I had. Sorry I should've included it.

Comment: Am I correct that this action is to be executed asynchronously  (ie Ajax)?

Comment: BTW sentence "problem.status ? problem.status : (problem.status == 'false')" doesn't make a lot of sense. First of all, it doesn't do anything, does not set any variable or change state etc. And second, if program went by "else" path then problem.status can't be =='false', because 'false', being string is considered to be true in  logical checks.

Comment: Teeg, no I don't think so, I'm not using any javascript to do this. TheRusskiy, you're right maybe I can fix this line.

Comment: That's the problem though, it doesn't work :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An http "GET" request sends its data to the controller via the query parameters (the part of the URL that looks like `?someAttribute=foo&someOtherAttribute=bar`).

The `link_to` helper can accept additional parameters which will be included in the generated URL as query parameters like I described above. The URL path helpers (such as `problem_path` for example), can do the same. For example: `problem_path(@problem, :additionalParam=>"someValue")`, which will generate something like `problem/1?additionalParam=someValue`.

You were on the right track with your last `link_to` example, you simply needed to add the additional parameters in a similar manner as described above. However, that method is unnecessarily verbose, when you can use url helpers instead.

If your requirement is to simply flop the boolean `status` field, the `show` action wouldn't be the appropriate place. I don't know if the `solve` action is intended to handle this flopping, but for clarity, we'll handle this activity in an action called `flop`, from which you can simply `redirect_to` the `show` action.

In your `routes.rb`, set up the `flop` action.

```
resources :problems do
    member do
        get :flop
    end
end
```

If you do a `rake routes`, you'll see you will have another URL helper that looks like:

```
flop_problem GET /problems/:id/flop(.:format) problem#flop
```

So you can write your button `link_to` like so:

```
link_to (@problem.status ? "Yes" : "No"), flop_problem_path(@problem)
```

Which leads to the `flop` action in the `ProblemController`:

```
def flop
    problem = Problem.find(params[:id])
    problem.status = !problem.status # flop the status
    problem.save

    redirect_to problem_path(problem)
end
```

The `show` action shouldn't need anything beyond loading up the problem object.

By the way, if you want to clean up the `link_to` code a little, add a method in the `Problem` model class:

```
class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
    # other code ...
    def status_name
        status ? "Yes" : "No"
    end
end
```

Which can be used like so:

```
link_to @problem.status_name, flop_problem_path(@problem)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find `params` in your post. That's the glue.

Also, your `? :` ternary operator does not do anything...

Comment: I have the params code, edited it in the post. You're right about the ternary operator, trying to fix it now.